# monacaにおけるonsen-uiのタブバーを用いたときのcssやjavascriptの有効について。

Tags: javascript, monaca, css, onsen-ui, html5

はじめまして。プログラミングを初めて3日目です。javascriptでゲームを作りたいです。(tmlib.jsフレームワークを使いたいです。)
monacaに登録し、onsen-uiのタブバーとスライディングバーのテンプレートを組み合わせてページ遷移を行うことが出来ました。
しかし、ページ遷移後にcssやjavascriptが実行できず困っています。
リンクを作り、person.html(目的ページ)を開くとCSSとjavascriptのalertは実行出来ています。
onsen-uiを用いるとjavascriptやcssを使うことはできないのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

index.htmlの一部

```
<ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-home" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="cutlery.html">
    <div class="notification reply-notification" ons-tab-inactive>4</div>
    <ons-icon icon="fa fa-cutlery" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="heart.html">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-heart" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="person.html">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-person" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
  </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

person.html(実行させたいjavascript,css等)

body {
background: #000fff
}

FONT size 7

a
    
    person

```
    <script>
        tm.main(function() {
            alert("tmlib.js バッチリ読み込まれてるよ！！");
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        // TODO: ここにコードを書いていく
        tm.main(function() {
            // アプリケーションクラスを生成
            var app = tm.display.CanvasApp("#world");

            // スターを生成してシーンに追加
            var star = tm.display.StarShape().addChildTo(app.currentScene);
            // 位置をセット
            star.setPosition(150, 75);
            // 更新処理を登録
            star.update = function() {
                // 回転
                this.rotation += 8;
            };

            // 実行
            app.run();
        });
    </script>
```

[image: タブバーでのページ遷移（javascript,cssが動いていない）]

Answer (score 1):

[タブバーの推移先のhtmlファイルでjsを実行する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12982/)

これやろ？
使ったことないけどアンギュラーが元やから色々面倒そうやな。
でも質問する前に検索はしたほうがええで。