# onsenui ons-navigatorのpushPage内でajax通信（jquery )は可能ですか？

Tags: onsen-ui

いつもお世話になっております。
onsenuiとjqueryでアプリを開発しているのですが、pushpage内でのjsの扱いで困っています。

現在ons-navigator内でjsによりアイテムの一覧をデータベースより取得・表示させています。
一覧の各アイテムをクリックでpushPage(詳細ページ）に移動する仕様にしております。

pushPage(詳細ページ）に移動した際リストページで取得したキーを元に再度データベースへデータを取りに行きたいのですが、ページ読み込み時にajax通信エラーが出てしまいます。

一旦親ページでデータを取得したpushPage内では再度データの取得はできないのでしょうか？

参考までに詳細ページ内でのjsは以下のように記載しております。

```
$(document.body).on("pageinit", '#hoge', function() {
    var options = myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options;
    var param = { "id": options.itemid};
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://sample.com/app/sample.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: JSON.stringify(param),
        success:function(xml){
            $("#done").html('<br><br>サーバーへの接続に成功');
        },
        error:function(){
            $("#err").html('<br><br>サーバーへの接続に失敗しました');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

OnsenUIで遷移した後もAjax通信をすることは可能です。

上記コードではHTMLのBODYが読み込み完了した際にしかよばれません。
似たような回答を下記でも行っていますが、
OnsenUIの遷移完了時に呼ばれる`ons.ready`を使用する必要があります。

「[タブバーの推移先のhtmlファイルでjsを実行する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12982/)」

```js
var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen']);
module.controller('page1_controller', function($scope) {
 ons.ready(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  $("#target").prepend(today.getDate());
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja" ng-app="my-app"><!--モジュール名を指定-->
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ons-page ng-controller="page1_controller"><!--コントローラークラスを割り当て-->
   <ons-toolbar> <div id="target" class="center"> 日 </div> </ons-toolbar> 
  </ons-page>
 </body>
</html>
```

また、Ajax通信でエラーが出ていると言う事ですが、エラー内容はどのような物でしょうか？
詳細を記述して頂ければ、もっと詳しい回答が出来るかもしれません。

Comment: おかげさまで無事jsを発火させられました。
ajaxエラーに関しては下記ご回答にもあるようにこちらの記載ミスでした。
お騒がせし申し訳ありませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

Ajaxの通信エラーの原因は、$.ajax のオプション指定が間違っているためではないかと思います。
どのようなリクエストを送っているのかわからないので、paramが正しいリクエストパラメータを表現したオブジェクトだとすると、

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://sample.com/app/sample.php",
    type:"POST",
    dataType: "json",    // <---- ※ここ
    data: param,         // <---- ※ここ
    success:function(xml){
        $("#done").html('<br><br>サーバーへの接続に成功');
    },
    error:function(){
        $("#err").html('<br><br>サーバーへの接続に失敗しました');
    }
});
```

と指定しないといけないのではないかと思います。ご確認ください。

また、「ページ遷移の度に取得」であれば、pageinitイベントではなく、ons-navigatorのpostpushイベントを使えば良いと思います。

Comment: おっしゃる通りでした。
初歩的なミスでお騒がせし申し訳ございません。